# call plsql procedure with parameters

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I tried to call this procedure but have some issues

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure InsertNewReservation
   ( flight_number IN varchar2,passenger_id IN number,flight_price in number )

   IS
   s2 number;

BEGIN
   insert into Reservations (flightNumber,passengerId) values (flight_number,passenger_id) 
                                                       returning ID into s2;

   insert into Payments (value,reservationId) values (flight_price,s2);
END;
/
```

How do I call the procedure ?
I tried

```
BEGIN
  InsertNewReservation('FL100',1,120);
END;
/
```

But it didn't work :/

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your procedure is not compiled correctly and is invalid. That usually happens when there is an syntax error. Make sure that everything is correct with your procedure.

Comment: It is not recommended to create stored procedures in SYS schema. Are you connecting to the database as SYS? If so, you should create a new user and create your stored procedures in his schema. For example, all the Oracle sample database objects, like the EMP table, exist in the SCOTT schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there's no `ID` column, but `passengerId` within the Reservations table :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure InsertNewReservation
                           ( 
                            flight_number Reservations.flightNumber%type,
                            passenger_id  Reservations.passengerId%type,
                            flight_price  Payments.value%type 
                           )
IS
   s2 Payments.reservationId%type;
BEGIN
   insert into Reservations (flightNumber,passengerId) 
   values(flight_number,passenger_id) returning passengerId into s2;

   insert into Payments (value,reservationId) Values (flight_price,s2);
END;
/
```

btw, replace the variables so as to conform their respective types within the table, and using `IN` operator is redundant for parameter type of the procedure as being the default.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=df02071ff3eeaed865f5c990d26957af)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `exec` keyword, which is not used in a PL/SQL block:

```
begin
  InsertNewReservation('FL100',1,120);
end;
```

`exec` is used in tools like SQL Plus to run a procedure outside a PL/SQL block:

```
SQL> exec InsertNewReservation('FL100',1,120);
```

Comment: Not working, Im getting a new error "Object SYS.INSERTNEWRESERVATION is invalid, statement ignored"

Comment: You didn't solve the issue... Barbaros Özhan did. Your answer just created another issue, therefore, it's not a usefull answer.....

Comment: I didn't solve the issue that you didn't post - right...  Goodbye